# Jira Script Runner - Mail is not sent by Post Function of Create Transition

Tags: email, groovy, scripting, jira

we have a Project in Jira which we use as an inbox for Email. Not all people sending emails are users in JIRA (and they shall not be). Nevertheless, we would like to inform then on having received the Email. The emailaddress is part of the Issue description.

I am aware of some plugins out there but instead of replacing the Mailhandlers, I am trying to write a groovy script for JIRA adapting [this code](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Post+Functions#PostFunctions-SendEmailWhenBlockerReported) which I want to post into a Post Function on the CREATE transition of a workflow.

The following code works fine when I grab an existing Test-Issue and run the script in the console:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.mail.Email
import com.atlassian.mail.server.MailServerManager
import com.atlassian.mail.server.SMTPMailServer

ComponentManager componentManager = ComponentManager.getInstance()
MailServerManager mailServerManager = componentManager.getMailServerManager()
SMTPMailServer mailServer = mailServerManager.getDefaultSMTPMailServer()

if (mailServer) {
    if (true) {  

        IssueManager issueManager = componentManager.getIssueManager()    
        Issue issue = issueManager.getIssueObject("IN-376")

        def grabEmail = {
            (((it.split(   "\\[Created via e-mail received from:")[1]).split("<")[1]).split(">")[0])
        }
        String senderAddress = grabEmail("${issue.description}")

        Email email = new Email(senderAddress) 
        email.setSubject("JIRA Ticket erstellt: ${issue.summary}") 
        String content = "Content ----> by Issue2 ${issue.description}"
        email.setBody(content)
        mailServer.send(email)


    }
}
```

Alas, it will not run in the Post Function like this:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
//import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.mail.Email
import com.atlassian.mail.server.MailServerManager
import com.atlassian.mail.server.SMTPMailServer

ComponentManager componentManager = ComponentManager.getInstance()
MailServerManager mailServerManager = componentManager.getMailServerManager()
SMTPMailServer mailServer = mailServerManager.getDefaultSMTPMailServer()

if (mailServer) {
    if (true) {  

        //IssueManager issueManager = componentManager.getIssueManager()    
        //Issue issue = issueManager.getIssueObject("IN-376")

        def grabEmail = {
            (((it.split(   "\\[Created via e-mail received from:")[1]).split("<")[1]).split(">")[0])
        }
        String senderAddress = grabEmail("${issue.description}")

        Email email = new Email(senderAddress) 
        email.setSubject("JIRA Ticket erstellt: ${issue.summary}") 
        String content = "Content ----> by Issue2 ${issue.description}"
        email.setBody(content)
        mailServer.send(email)


    }
}
```

I have no idea why the second code breaks since the code this is based on uses issue also as if it is implicitly defined. This Post function is the last to run.

I would also find hints as to debugging this problem helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: How to debug? I once used the issue to output my debug messages. Put your code in a try-catch-block and send your exception to the description of the issue. This also works fine for other types of debug messages...

Comment: have you enabled the outgoing mail function?.

Comment: @user880772: In the second some lines are commented out

Comment: @Nuwan: yes, and the first code does send mails

Comment: I did not find an error in any of the logs, then. Maybe I oversaw it, sorry, but I have changed a lot of config by now (installing JEMH trial) so I can not reproduce. Strangely enough, the message gets sent right now, so I have that ill feeling that I had some config in the Notifications Scheme wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post my comment as an answer: I did not find an error in any of the logs, then. Maybe I oversaw it, sorry, but I have changed a lot of config by now (installing JEMH trial) so I can not reproduce. Strangely enough, the message gets sent right now, so I have that ill feeling that I had some config in the Notifications Scheme wrong.

Thanks everyone for the help and time.